# Upload files to object storage using python SDK

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-python-sdk

I am using Python SDK for OCI. I tried the Upload manager example and its working perfectly fine when i try to upload files from file system. But i have to expose this python code as REST service (using flask) and files to be uploaded to object storage will come as payload for REST. Does it have to multipart/mixed content type in this case or can it be multipart/form-data as well.

Answer (score 0):

@user1945183, are you asking if Upload Manager can support multipart/form-data? Yes, Upload Manager can take in multipart/form-data.

The Upload Manager uses Object Storage's CreateMultipartUpload API. You can learn more about the [CreateMultipartUpload API](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/objectstorage/20160918/MultipartUpload/CreateMultipartUpload) doc.

From [CreateMultipartUploadDetails Reference](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/objectstorage/20160918/datatypes/CreateMultipartUploadDetails) you will find that content-type is optional and have no effect on Object Storage behavior.

```
The optional Content-Type header that defines the standard MIME type format of 
the object to upload. Specifying values for this header has no effect on 
Object Storage behavior. Programs that read the object determine what to do 
based on the value provided. For example, you could use this header to 
identify and perform special operations on text only objects.
```